# CORS error on localhost for Laravel API for Angular and working on Postman

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I have one Laravel API and an Angular frontend. When the API is hosted on a server and I use the URL in Angular, everything is working fine. But when I am trying the API as localhost, it is not working and throwing the following error.

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8088/my-api/public/api/v1/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for 
 protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I am able to access the API from Postman and getting the desired response.

I have the following code in the `Kernal`

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

Also in the `config/cors.php`, I have

```
return [

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

I am using an application called `Wamp` for setting up the local development server. Also tried to delete the cache and compiled sources, but nothing is working. How can I get this working on the local server ?

My Laravel version is `7.25.0`

Comment: laravel version ?

Comment: Laravel Version is `7.25.0`

Comment: you are using https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors this right ?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same

Comment: `config/cors.php`  add route `paths`

Comment: `['api/*']` or `['*']` if u want for all route

Comment: It is already there. I have `[api/*]`

Comment: may be restart server and angular both

Comment: have u checked this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-cors-errors-with-angular-cli-proxy-e5e0ef143f85

Comment: Your url.is localhost:8088/my-api/public/api/v1/auth/login. Your cors allows api/*. I suspect that that is the issue. Change that to '*' maybe?

Comment: already done it. But the error is still there.

Comment: You forgot the protocol for your api url.. i.e. your url is not valid.